# Google apps script to stop the trigger on specific days

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script function, and I created a trigger to run every hour

I need to stop that trigger at specific day and times
for example I don't want to run it from Friday 5pm until Saturday 10pm

I found a function to stop it by day

```
//Skip week-end
var day = new Date();
if (day.getDay()>5 || day.getDay()==0) {
  return;
}
```

but I don't know how to accomplish to be more specific from Friday 5pm until Saturday 10pm to don't run it

any help please ?

Comment: Review the event object for time-based triggers, or any of the many other questions about running functions only in a certain time window. Review also the JavaScript `Date` object if you are not familiar with its methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to include a check inside the trigger function to skip processing if the date and time fall in the specified period.

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var date = new Date();
  var day = days[date.getDay()];
  var hours = date.getHours();
  if ((day === "Fri" && hours >= 17) || (day === "Sat" && hours <= 22)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function myTrigger() {
  if (!shouldRunTrigger()) return;
  // trigger code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to work perfect, If I also want to exclude an specific date is it possible to add another if statement ? for example I don't want it to run from Sun 24 March 3pm until Wed 27 March 8pm, thanks for your time !!!

Comment: You can add any number or criteria.

Comment: Ive been trying to do the example to don't  run from Sun 24 March 3pm until Wed 27 March 8pm, but I don't know how to do it, can you please help me on that ? I will very much appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is the simplest way it's skip current execution without re-create the trigger.

Suppose the days are hundreds:

- Friday is `500`
- Saturday - `600`

Suppose the hours are dozens and units:

- 01:00 - `1`
- 17:00 - `17`
- 22:00 - `22`

Then we have to pause between `500 + 17` and up to `600 + 22`.

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var now = new Date();
  var k = now.getDay() * 100 + now.getHours() + now.getMinutes()/100;
  return !(k >= 517 && k < 622);
}

function myTrigger() {
  if (!shouldRunTrigger()) return; // If true then skip it
  // trigger code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain me a little the code to understand ? ... this means exactly what im looking for to don't run the trigger from Friday 5pm until Saturday 10pm ?, thanks for your time