# Google apps script to stop the trigger on specific date ranges

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to prevent a trigger to run at specific times, thanks to [Amit Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136413/8581604) who helped me on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135702/google-apps-script-to-stop-the-trigger-on-specific-days/55136413#55136413)

The script is this:

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var date = new Date();
  var day = days[date.getDay()];
  var hours = date.getHours();
  if ((day === "Fri" && hours >= 17) || (day === "Sat" && hours <= 22)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function myTrigger() {
  if (!shouldRunTrigger()) return;
  // trigger code here
}
```

This code prevents my trigger to run from Fri 5pm until Sat 10pm, and its working great.

Now what I need is to add another `else if` to prevent the trigger to run at specific range dates, for example:

- I want to don't run it from march 23th 3pm until march 25 5pm
- I was trying to accomplish that without luck

anyone can help me to add this `if else` condition please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by comparing the current date with a Date object as shown below:

```
function shouldRunTrigger() {
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var date = new Date();
  var day = days[date.getDay()];
  var hours = date.getHours();
  if ((day === "Fri" && hours >= 17) && (day === "Sat" && hours <= 22)) {
    return false;
  }
  else if(date >= new Date('2019-03-23T15:00:00') || date <= new Date('2019-03-25T17:00:00')) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function myTrigger() {
  if (!shouldRunTrigger()) return;
  // trigger code here
}
```

The Date object in JavaScript, is in the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format. More information from the MDN web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Hi, this looks a good idea, the problem is I'm doing It, but it never runs the trigger, even if I change the dates for April or any dates, im always gettin return false;   do you know how to fix it ? thanks

Comment: I have changed the || for && and now is working perfect

Comment: Sorry! My bad, it is supposed to be && as it needs to come within the date range. The || was returning false for any date after the first parameter and any date before the second parameter which caused the `else if` statement to `return false` for every date passed in. I've **corrected my answer**! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another check in the shouldRunTrigger() method.

```
var current = new Date()
var min = new Date(2019,2,23,15);
var max = new Date(2019,2,25,17);
if (current > min && current < max) return false;
```

Comment: Should that be an `&&`?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `||` for `&&` and now is working perfectly.

The final code working for this is:

```
else if (date >= new Date('2019-03-10T15:00:00') && date <= new Date('2019-04-25T17:00:00')) {
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for your help!